# How do I troubleshoot a Nikon D3000 'lens not attached' problem?

Tags: troubleshooting, lens-mount, error, nikon-d3000

Recently my Nikon d3000 started the 'lens not attached' error. I have two lenses, neither of which work. I tried the lenses in another camera body, and they work fine. I have cleaned the contact points and tried reattaching the lens, making sure the lens is connected, and nothing works. Any other suggestions? The warranty ran out about a week prior to this happening.

Comment: The lenses *did* work on **that body** before though, right?

Comment: Sure did. They are both Nikon lenses. I've had the camera body and the two lenses since August '10. Just went out about a week or two ago, and I haven't been able to get them to work since, and the nearest camera shop is over an hour away.

Comment: Did you clean the contacts on both the lens and the camera?

Comment: What are the lenses? If you are using lenses with aperture ring, make sure it is locked to the maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have already cleaned the contacts (how have you cleaned them? I would have adviced ethanol on a smooth and clean material...), you have almost no choice left: you need to bring your camera body and optics back to the shop you bought them to or to refer to the Nikon customers service. Sorry...

Comment: P.S. As the warranty period has ended just a week or two from now, I would try to have Nikon make a "commercial" effort for you. Indeed, the D3000 is not exactly a cheap device and you are a valuable customer. Moreover, Nikon, as a Japanese company, need nothing but loosing customers in the the current context. Try to phone their hotline and contact them on their website.