# "Lens not attached" error with new Sigma 150-500 zoom lens on Nikon D3300

Tags: lens, troubleshooting, error, nikon-d3300

I received my sigma 150-500mm F/5-6.3 zoom lens. I connected my lens to my Nikon D3300 which is compatible. When I take a picture the picture is black. I think it's because the shutter is closed. I can't seem to get it to open up. It also reads that the lens is not attached.

Comment: How do you know it's compatible?  Clearly it's reporting an incompatible, or at least incorrectly attached, lens.  I'm guessing the shutter won't open when the camera thinks theres no lens.

Comment: Have you removed the lens cap?

Comment: Does the camera work with a different lens? If you remove the lens from the camera, and look through the optics, can you see right through?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I troubleshoot a Nikon D3000 'lens not attached' problem?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14491/how-do-i-troubleshoot-a-nikon-d3000-lens-not-attached-problem)

Comment: When I bought the camera it said it was compatible. The camera does work with other lenses. Yes I can see through the optics.

Comment: The Nikon d3XXX and d5XXX line do not have AF motors. Perhaps the lens requires it? I've used a similar lens, 150-600, on my Sony 6000 and I've had no problems. The only thing I can think of is no aperture control on the d3300 so you're shooing at f22 which makes it black.

Comment: What is the light meter reading?

Comment: No, that's a modern lens that's available in Canon, Nikon, and Sigma mounts.  It does not need a mechanical AF motor in the camera.

Answer (score 1):

If the camera cannot communicate with the lens, it cannot tell the lens to open the aperture to let the right amount of light in, and it probably will meter based on the assumption that the aperture is much wider than it actually is because it can't read the current aperture position from the lens.

Bottom line: Try cleaning the contacts.  If that doesn't work, contact the lens manufacturer or the seller, because the lens's electronics are DOA.

Comment: Nikon bodies don't usually tell the lens to open the aperture, they control it via a mechanical part. Newer Nikon lenses have electronic apertures, but those are wide open by default.

Comment: Ah, but remember that this isn't a Nikon lens.  This is a Sigma lens, which is a lens that has to be compatible with multiple different bodies by multiple different manufacturers.  I'd be willing to bet that the aperture even in the Nikon version is entirely electronic.  Besides, the important part is not whether the aperture is wide open, but rather whether the camera assumes that you've attached a manual aperture lens set to... say f/2 when in reality "wide open" for that lens is really f/5 or f/6.3.  :-)

Comment: @dgatwood: I doubt a lens as old as that would have had fully electronic  aperture control as it would have made it incompatible with a lot of Nikon bodies in use at the time (e.g. D90)

Comment: Are you sure that those cameras don't support type G lenses?  Nikon's docs say that they do.  Either way, though, it's the aperture detection that matters, not the aperture control.